# SFMC AB Testing

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm planning on doing an AB subject line test with an audience size of over 1M.

I'm probably going to do 20% Subject A, 20% Subject B and 60% receive the remainder based on opens. I plan to test both subjects for about 4 hours due to the time sensitive promotion.

My question is, if I run my test from 6AM-10AM and the winner is sent thereafter automatically, will the system send the full 60% (remainder audience) within the hour since there is no throttling within the AB testing tool. Ideally, I would like to have the remainder sent fully within 2 hours at least.

Is this the case with SFMC? Will it be able to push out 600K within 2 hours?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The send speed would largely depend on the level of complexity and scripted content along with server loads at the time of send. If you're email's largely static, that send speed wouldn't be a challenge at all. I've seen accounts without any SLAs purchased or use of burst sending happily send at around 7-10 million per hour. If you have lots of dynamic content, lookups to Data Extensions or, even worse, content syndication for each email being sent, 300K per hour could easily be unattainable.